# How to programmatically mute other applications sound using Win32 API

Tags: winapi, audio, mute

I cannot find any useful information on this topic.  If someone could shed light on this, I would be very appreciative.

I am almost done developing a business telephony application for our company; it will use either wireless/wired headsets or special USB telephone-like devices through which the audio for telephone communications will be played and received.  The only thing is if our employees have noisy websites up or Pandora playing while they're there working, I need to enumerate and mute all the other potential noisy-ness, even system noises, while they deal with the customer on the phone.

The users will not be running the software as administrator.

I have used PureBasic for most of the UI, and networking.  It has easy, native support for the Windows API. If I need to use COM, I use C++ (VS2010) to write small "plug-in" applications that communicate with the PureBasic application using XML by redirecting stdin/out.

I have seen other posts similar to this topic with people replying along the lines of this idea being a bad idea...and talking about what would happen in everyone's applications went to war over sound devices and such.  But this, as far as I can tell, is the ONLY feasible solution to our problem.  We don't want ANY audio distractions when our customer service reps are on the phone with our customers.

I've been looking at the mixer...() functions on MSDN, but I can't quite tell if they'll work.  So if anyone has experience in this area it would be great to hear from them!